# qplot gives error "Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems" when I subset the data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, subset

I am trying to plot the origin and the delay in time in the Airline Dataset that i got online. It works fine when I use the entire dataset.

```
qplot(origin,delay,data = mydata,stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean')
```

while I get the error

> `Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:origin`

when I try this after sub-setting the data. This is the code I used.

```
qplot(origin,delay,data = subset(mydata,state=='TX'),stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean')
```

I tried the same with the base plotting system too.It works fine with whole data

```
with(mydata,plot(origin,delay))
```

but fails when subsetted

```
with(subset(mydata,state=='TX'),plot(origin,delay))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x) :variable lengths differ (found for 'x')
```

Comment: How about `qplot(origin,delay,data = subset(mydata, state %in% 'TX'),stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean')`?

Comment: please provide the output of `dput(mydata)`

Comment: Can't tell much without an example dataset, but this can happen if you created a new variable but didn't add it to your dataset.